# Check instance status using filter with EC2 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to make sure the instance has passed the two status checks(System/Instance reachability check) using command line.

When I run this

```
ec2-describe-instance-status
ec2-describe-instance-status XX($InstanceID)
```

it would show running instances like

```
INSTANCE    $InstanceID $REGION running 16
```

But when I tried adding a filter to make sure the instance passed the status check

```
ec2-describe-instance-status XX($InstanceID) --filter instance-status.reachability=passed
ec2-describe-instance-status XX($InstanceID) --filter "instance-status.reachability=passed"
ec2-describe-instance-status --filter instance-status.reachability=passed
```

nothing ever returned.

I've double-checked the instances are running fine and actually passed the 2 status checks, but why nothing is returned after applying the filters?

**Update:**
In response to Rico, I tried the `-v` option

```
ec2-describe-instance-status -v
```

returns one item in the instanceStatusSet, with the fields

```
    <item>
      <instanceId>i-XXX</instanceId>
      <availabilityZone>us-east-1d</availabilityZone>
      <instanceState>
        <code>16</code>
        <name>running</name>
      </instanceState>
    </item>
```

while

```
ec2-describe-instance-status --filter instance-status.reachability=passed -v
ec2-describe-instance-status --filter "instance-status.reachability=passed" -v
```

both return an empty instanceStatusSet...

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you try running it with the verbose option ?  `ec2-describe-instance-status --filter instance-status.reachability=passed -v`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but still failed. I'll update this in the post.

Comment: Or are there any other ways to check the status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) unified tool instead.

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids i-01234567 --filters Name=instance-status.reachability,Values=passed
{
"InstanceStatuses": [
    {
        "InstanceId": "i-01234567",
        "InstanceState": {
            "Code": 16,
            "Name": "running"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
        "SystemStatus": {
            "Status": "ok",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "Status": "passed",
                    "Name": "reachability"
                }
            ]
        },
        "InstanceStatus": {
            "Status": "ok",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "Status": "passed",
                    "Name": "reachability"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for checking back late. Thanks for the answer!